# Calling my own R routines with Python

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I want to call a complex algorithm coded in R from python.

Looking at the RPY2 package documentation I understand that I can call many standard R functions using the robjects package.

I was wondering if this could be extended to my own R routines. 
Should I package my R stuff or could I use my code as is? Is there a way I could make it accessible?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to make an R package. Rpy2 can evaluate strings as R code.
There is also a convenience system to [evaluate a string with R code and wrap it as if it was a package](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/robjects_rpackages.html#importing-arbitrary-r-code-as-a-package).

Comment: Thanks. I tried both and I will go with the package. But thanks for the constructive answer to that simple problem @lgautier